# Change command in package

Tags: macros, packages, package-writing, venn-diagrams, robust-commands

Im trying to use the `venndiagram` package but i want to change the colour it fills in the areas. Currently if you use the code for example

```
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
\fillOnlyA \fillNotAorB \fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
```

[image]

It will give a venn diagram with some bits filled in as gray. However i wish to make it a bit more colourful, maybe red. so im wishing to change a little bit in the package.

```
\begin{macro}{\@venn@shade}
% The colour used to shade regions.
\begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\@venn@shade}{lightgray}
\end{macrocode}
\end{macro}
```

So it will be red instead of light gray and i cant work it out. I have tried

```
\renewcommand{\@venn@shade}{red}
```

but it just comes up with a error.

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable ... And add the error you got to your question, copy the complete message from the log file ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track trying to renew `\@venn@shade` but to do that you need to wrap the `\renewcommand` in `\makeatletter` `\makeatother`. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/)

You can also modify aspects of the `tikzpicture` environment used to draw the venn diagram by using the option `tikzoptions=`. In this way you can modify the colour of the lines used to draw the sets, the line thickness and so on.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@venn@shade}{red!20}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={draw=blue,thick}]
\fillOnlyA \fillNotAorB \fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]